# Unrecognized escape sequence in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have strings like this in my database :

> "\12 stack"

or

> "\11 stack + \12 overflow"

When I try to parse and process those strings I get this  for each "\" character:

> Unrecognized escape sequence

I know when I add "@" character before the string, the problem is solved.
For example :

```
string mystring = @"\11 stack + \12 overflow";
```

But how can I do that programmatically when I retrieve such strings? Or is there any other workaround? Thanks.

Comment: What operation are you performing on the string for it to return that error?

Comment: Could you add the code on how you retrieve it from your database?

Comment: If the string is actually stored in your database as `\12....` then this shouldn't be a problem. So you are either not storing it in the database how you think you are, or else you are doing something odd to the string after you retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is a bunch of `char`s.
If you type a backslash inside of a string i.e. "\n", this is being converted by the compiler to a **single** char that represents the 'new line' character.

The `@"\n"` notifies the compiler that it needs to treat this string with each char for itself (meaning '\' concatenated with 'n')

If you get programmatically a string containing a special char you don't have to worry about it since it's already represented as a single char.

Answer (score 3):

The blackslash is a special character used to build strings. To represent a single blackslash you need to use "\\":

```
"\\11 stack + \\12 overflow"
```